# Add attribute to class list to return all objects with specific attribute

Tags: python, list, class, filter, attributes

I have the following problem:

**Let's set the scene!**

Say I have a class Person with a few basic attributes:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, gender=None, single=None):
        self.name=name
        self.gender=gender
        self.single=single
```

And I create a list class called Dating, which will hold all Person objects

```
class Dating(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.members=[]

My_People=Dating()

My_People.members.append(Person("Jack","Male",False))
My_People.members.append(Person("Jill","Female",True))
My_People.members.append(Person("George","Male",True))
My_People.members.append(Person("Sandy","Female",False))
```

**Right, so what is the problem?**

Is it possible to assign an attribute to the list class to access single members of the My_People list by creating some sort of attribute like:

```
My_People.members.singles
```

So that this would return a list of Person objects that have the *single == True* attribute?

Thanks for all the help. (by the way, I have got very little previous experience with Python)

Comment: stop calling an `__init__` method, it does work this way without your help)

Comment: Have edited the question. Better now?

Comment: Anyone know why this was downvoted? Feedback is useful so I can edit the question and hopefully resolve the issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add attributes like that, you'd have to *subclass* the list type:

```
class FilterableList(list):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # assume non-existing attributes are boolean filters
        return [elem for elem in self if getattr(elem, name)]
```

Note that this is not all that flexible; only `True` values are found this way. You can give the attribute names more meaning, but *usually* you'd want to do this on the `Dating` class anyway and use *methods* to filter your data more expressively.

Demo:

```
>>> class Person(object):
...     def __init__(self, name, gender, single):
...         self.name=name
...         self.gender=gender
...         self.single=single
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'Person({name!r}, {gender!r}, {single!r})'.format(**vars(self))
... 
>>> class FilterableList(list):
...     def __getattr__(self, name):
...         # assume non-existing attributes are boolean filters
...         return [elem for elem in self if getattr(elem, name)]
... 
>>> members = FilterableList([Person("Jack","Male",False), Person("Jill","Female",True), Person("George","Male",True), Person("Sandy","Female",False)])
>>> members
[Person('Jack', 'Male', False), Person('Jill', 'Female', True), Person('George', 'Male', True), Person('Sandy', 'Female', False)]
>>> members.single
[Person('Jill', 'Female', True), Person('George', 'Male', True)]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it is exactly what I need and I love the flexibility of your solution. Also, I've never used __repr__ before and it really will come in handy too!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you don't need to call `__init__()` on the `My_People` instance, Python does that automatically.

For the question, you could subclass from `list` and add a `singles` property like this:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, gender=None, single=None):
        self.name=name
        self.gender=gender
        self.single=single

class Dating(list):
    @property
    def singles(self):
        return [person for person in self if person.single ]

My_People=Dating()

My_People.append(Person("Jack","Male",False))
My_People.append(Person("Jill","Female",True))
My_People.append(Person("George","Male",True))
My_People.append(Person("Sandy","Female",False))

print My_People.singles
```

Comment: great, I understand this. So you have to iterate through the My_People list each time you want to access My_People.singles and there is no direct way of calling out those objects with the single==True attribute.

Comment: I like the suggestion to subclass from list, very handy

Comment: @user1083734 You could of course save the results which ``.singles`` return to avoid iterating over the list on every access.

Comment: but then wouldn't I would have to update the singles results by calling the function again every time the My_People list changes?

Answer (score 1):

How about that:

```
class Attribute(list):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr == 'single':
            return [person for person in self if person.single]
        raise AttributeError()

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, gender=None, single=None):
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender
        self.single = single

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Person({person.name}, {person.gender}, {person.single})'.format(person=self)


class Dating(object):
    members = Attribute()


My_People = Dating()

My_People.members.append(Person("Jack", "Male", False))
My_People.members.append(Person("Jill", "Female", True))
My_People.members.append(Person("George", "Male", True))
My_People.members.append(Person("Sandy", "Female", False))

>>> print My_People.members.single
[Person(Jill, Female, True), Person(George, Male, True)]
>>> print My_People.members
[Person(Jack, Male, False), Person(Jill, Female, True), Person(George, Male, True), Person(Sandy, Female, False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not tied to the `My_People.members.singles` syntax, you could do this much more simply:

```
class Dating(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.members = []

    @property
    def single_members(self):
        return [m for m in members if m.single]
```

Now you access the list with:

```
My_People.single_members
```